# Table View Cells change Height when cell tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have a **TableView with 3 custom cells**.

[image]

When one of the **cells is tapped** on and goes to the WebView, the **table view cells change heights for some reason**.  And then when I **go back** to the TableView from the WebView I can see the **table view cells change heights**.

I assume this has to do with the height of the cells being wrong somehow, but I don't know for sure.  Here's what I've tried:

1.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {
        return 490; // As of 11/13/14
    } else { // 2 other custom cells
        return tableView.rowHeight; // return the default height
    }
}
```

2.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {
    ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];
    CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightOne + 2;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {
    ListTableViewCellTwo *cellTwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"2Cell"];
    CGFloat heightTwo = [cellTwo.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightTwo + 400;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[YR self]]) {
    ListTableViewCellThree *cellThree = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"3Cell"];
    CGFloat heightThree = [cellThree.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return heightThree + 2;

    } else {
        return 175;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {

        FR *fD = (FR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];

        NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];

        NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

        NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

        1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
        1Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
        1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

                return 1Cell;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[YR self]]) {

        YR *fD = (YR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *3Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"3Cell"];

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];

        NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];

        NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

        NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

        3Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
        3Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
        3Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        return 3Cell;

            } else {

        D *dD = (D *)model;

        ListTableViewCellTwo *2Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"2Cell"];

        NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:dD.created_time];
        NSString *cap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dD.cap.text];
        NSString *us = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dD.us.use];

        2Cell.labelHeadline.text = us;
        2Cell.labelDescription.text = cap;
        2Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        return 2Cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Remove grey background from Highlighted State
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE per Matt Tang:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];


    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {


        ListTableViewCell *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];
        if (!1Cell) {
            1Cell = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

            1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
            1Cell.labelDescription.text = [description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }
        CGFloat heightOne = [1Cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;


    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[YR self]]) {


        ListTableViewCellThree  *3Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"3Cell"];
        if (!3Cell) {
            3Cell = [[ListTableViewCellThree alloc] init];

            YR *fD = (YR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

            3Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
            3Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
            3Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }
        CGFloat heightThree = [3Cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightThree + 2;


    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {


        ListTableViewCellTwo *2Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"2Cell"];
        if (!2Cell) {
            2Cell = [[ListTableViewCellTwo alloc] init];

            D *dD = (D *)model;
            NSString *dateStringI = [self timeSincePublished:dD.created_time];
            NSString *TI = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dD.caption.text];
            NSString *us = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dD.us.use];

            2Cell.labelHeadline.text = us;
            2Cell.labelDescription.text = cap;
            2Cell.labelPublished.text = dateStringI;
        }
        CGFloat heightTwo = [2Cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightTwo + 450;


    } else {

        return 490;
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {

        FR *fD = (FR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];

        if (!1Cell) {
            1Cell = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

            1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
            1Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
            1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        }

        return 1Cell;

    }

    // more code
    FR *fD = (FR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];

        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];

        NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];

        NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

        NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

        1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
        1Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
        1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        return 1Cell;

}
```

`CustomCell2.h` (`CustomCell2.m` has nothing in it right now):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelHeadline;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelPublished;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewPic;
```

Trying to set breakpoints too.

Comment: When you return from the webview, do you reload the table view cells?  Try putting `[[self tableView] reloadData];` in your viewWillAppear.

Comment: @JAL Yeah I have tried that.  The weird part is that its happening on the way TO the next `ViewController` as well as back FROM the next `ViewController`.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show to code that run when a cell is being selected? Since it only happens when a user taps on a cell, maybe it's something there...

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or something else?  Just let me know and I'll be happy to post

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}` <-- thats all `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is

Comment: Show cellForRowAtIndexPath also. Edit your question to put the code there; don't put code in comments. You shouldn't need to do anything other than what you're doing in method 1. You should put a log in the if clause (just above return 490), and see if that's called at all when you tap a cell. You might also try disconnecting the segue from the cell to see if you get the size change just from tapping without the segue happening.

Comment: @rdelmar just put that code in there because it was essentially no code, but I'll keep that in mind.  I disconnected the segue from the cell and the size change was not happening just from tapping.  I added the code per editing my question, let me know if anything else would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: It' hard to tell what you're doing if you don't post your actual code. You have all kinds of name conflicts between the model name and the model class names, as well as the names of the cells you create vs. the ones you return. That being said, I'm still not seeing anything that should cause your problem. You may have to post this project somewhere to get a good answer.

Comment: Cleaned up the code, so hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to change the way you've implemented tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

You call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to get your Custom cell object back to find its height. That method only keeps track of the cells that are visible on your screen. When you leave that tableview it will empty itself.

What you need to do is check to see if nil is returned after you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
***edit** You should actually use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

If it is nil, you'll have to create a temporary cell, configure it, and return its height.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {
        ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cellOne) {
            cellOne = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];
            NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

            cellOne.labelHeadline.text = title;
            cellOne.labelDescription.text = description;
            cellOne.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }

        // Make sure the cell's frame is updated
        [cellOne setNeedsLayout];
        [cellOne layoutIfNeeded];

        CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;

    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {

    // more code
}
```

If you want to follow the DRY principle, create a method called something like

```
- (ListTableViewCell *)configureCellForModel:(id)model;
```

And have all of your custom cell config code based on the model class in there. Have it return the cell and call it in both tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

**Update sample**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[FR self]]) {

        FR *fD = (FR *)model;

        ListTableViewCell  *1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell"];

        if (!1Cell) {
            1Cell = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];

            1Cell.labelHeadline.text = title;
            1Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
            1Cell.labelPublished.text = dateString;

        }

        return 1Cell;

    }

    // more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  `self.combinedModel` is actually supposed to be `self.model` my bad, I changed that.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I added something to my answer.

Comment: Yeah if I do what you suggested, all of the cells stay at exactly 100, with no jumping.  Any ideas on how to get it where I can not hardcode that value in there, since I have 3 custom cells using AutoLayout?

Comment: Excellent, going to try implementing right now and will let you know!

Comment: (BTW thanks I feel like this is going in the right direction)

Comment: Sorry, no error.  Do I need to add the `if(!cellOne)` code into my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` too?  Also, does anything look wrong with my code I wrote per your answer that you can see?

Comment: Yeah, you should check it in cellForRowAtIndexPath too. Also look at my edit on my answer. Use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of just dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Comment: For whatever reason using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` gave me a crash "THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)"... any reason for that or modification I should make?

Comment: Never mind. Switch back to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Comment: K.  Does my code look Ok?  I'm sorta still getting jumps, but I'm also getting part of some cells labels cut off.  However when I change something like `return heightOne + 2;` to `return heightOne + 100;` then it doesn't cut off the labels.  But if I do that then it wouldn't seem to be taking advantage of AutoLayout and re-sizing it correctly?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what the problem was.  Like if it wasn't taking into account some sizing or item in the table view cell, but I can't figure that out

Comment: I also added "UPDATE sample" to my original question to show what type of thing I added for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, does that look right to you for checking in case the cell is `nil`?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, lots of things could be making it jump. I added something to my answer which you should add before each systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: call in the heightForRowAtIndexPath: method. In your custom cell file, are you adding all of the labels/views to the contentView?

Comment: I will add the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` right now.  In my custom cell file, I commented everything out in the `ListViewCell.m` file now (commented out `layoutSubviews`) because I have been trying to figure out this issue and it didn't seem like anything there was needed.  In the `ListViewCell.h` file I have all of the property's hooked up to their outlet in the Storyboard (`labelHeadline` + `labelDescription` etc).  Does that all sound good, or does something sound like its missing?  Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my "Sample update", is that what the `//more code` part is supposed to have?  Because I'm not sure where I would have put that code otherwise, and it has to go somewhere I assume.  Thanks Matt!

Comment: So I've been still working on this trying different things, and if I use `return 490` and `return 175` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` then I don't get any jumping.  (I tried this instead of `CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;` because it was still jumping)

Comment: But for the `return 175` cells (`1Cell` and `3Cell`) that's setting the height explicitly at `175` instead of using AutoLayout to let the cell set its own height variably per the text in the labels.  How would I work around this?  Because it seems like its specifically that `return` code as the culprit from what I'm seeing?  Trying to get that `return` part right.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. It could be how you've configured your custom cells. Are all the labels/sub views added to the custom cell's contentView? Have you used view debugging yet? This may help you figure it out visually: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009986-CH10-SW1

Comment: I have tried the view debugging, but didn't find anything in it that cracked the nut on this one.  I posted my Custom Cell code for you in my Question update.  I really don't have any code in there, except for the properties for the labels/image.  That's the spot where I have all of those outlets connected.  Then I just call that code in my `TableViewController.m`.  That make sense?  Thanks Matt!

Comment: Its not 100 times out of 100, but when my view "jumps" it usually jumps DOWN like 40 pixels (hard to catch exactly with my eye in that short of time, but thats my guess, even tho sometimes its a bit more or a bit less).  Would that lead you to believe that there's something around 40px that's not calculating until the cell gets tapped or something?  I dunno, I feel like it MIGHT be a clue, but I have no idea.

Comment: Any ideas on my last few bits of info, and how maybe I could update my code to fix this?  Thanks Matt!

Comment: When I do `CGFloat heightOne = [1Cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height' and use a breakpoint to check what `heightOne` is, I seem to be getting 0 for some reason.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I see. Try to add a breakpoint to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath after the code where you configure 1Cell. Check to see if there's anything configured at that moment. tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath should be called after so it should also hit the original breakpoint you've set.